# C++ Error: Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting rid of a couple of compile errors in my code. I've used similar syntax elsewhere in the program without a problem, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

In PersonalRec.h:

```
#ifndef PersonalRec_H
#define PersonalRec_H

class PersonalRec
{
public:
    PersonalRec ();
    PersonalRec (string fName, string lName, Date bDate); //This line shows the first error
protected:
    void displayPersonalRec() const;
    int getAgeInYears() const;

private:
    std::string FirstName;
    std::string LastName;
    Date DoB;
};

#endif
```

In PersonalRec.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

#include "Date.h" //contains prototypes for Date class
#include "PersonalRec.h"

extern Date currentDate;

PersonalRec::PersonalRec()
{
}

PersonalRec::PersonalRec(string fName, string lName, Date bDate) //This line shows the second error
{
    FirstName = fName;
    LastName = lName;
    DoB = bDate;
    displayPersonalRec();
}

//Implementations of protected methods follow
```

The compiler errors read

> PersonalRec.h: error: expected ')' before 'fName'

and

> PersonalRec.cpp: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

I have a feeling they are related.

EDIT - The first error can be fixed by prefacing string fName into std::string fName and the same for lName. The modified code for that line is

```
PersonalRec (std::string fName, std::string lName, Date bDate);
```

EDIT 2 - I did the same thing for the second error and the code compiles.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need

```
#include <string>
```

in your .h file and that you need to prefix string with std::string there.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.
EDIT - It got rid of the first error, but the second is still there.